# Fiber product of an elliptic surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Let $f:S\to P^1$ be a smooth elliptic surface and let $X=S\times_{P^1} S$ be the fiber product. The threefold $X$ is singular in general (typically isolated ODPs). But is $X$ $\mathbb Q$-factorial? Or, are there conditions on $f$ that ensures this?

Comment: That will essentially never happen. Suppose that a fiber has an ordinary double point $p$, so that locally (analytically) at $p$ $f$ is given by $(x,y)\mapsto xy$. Then around $(p,p)$ $X$ is isomorphic to a cone over a smooth quadric, which is not $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial.

Comment: Great, thanks! Is the same true for $Hilb^2(S/P^1)$?